# Solidity Array Element Access

Tags: solidity, truffle-compile

In Truffle's [pet-shop tutorial](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop). Adoption.sol is --

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract Adoption {
    address[16] public adopters;

    // Adopting a pet
    function adopt(uint petId) public returns (uint) {
        require(petId >= 0 && petId <= 15);

        adopters[petId] = msg.sender;

        return petId;
    }   
}
```

TestAdoption.sol is --

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/Adoption.sol";

contract TestAdoption {
    Adoption adoption = Adoption(DeployedAddresses.Adoption());

    // Testing retrieval of a single pet's owner
    function testGetAdopterAddressByPetId() public {
        // Expected owner is this contract
        address expected = this;

        address adopter = adoption.adopters(8);

        Assert.equal(adopter, expected, "Owner of pet ID 8.");
    }   
}
```

My question is on the line `address adopter = adoption.adopters(8);` in TestAdoption.sol I thought adoption.adopters is an array and its element should be accessed via `[8]` instead of `(8)`.

However, Truffle's code is correct. In fact, changing `(8)` to `[8]` will result in Solidity compilation error --

```
TypeError: Indexed expression has to be a type, mapping or array (is function (uint256) view external returns (address))
        address adopter = adoption.adopters[8];
                          ^---------------^
```

What's the theory behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct access to the fields from another contract. The public keyword in `address[16] public adopters` will generate a getter function with the same name, hence `adoption.adopters(8)`.